# Ubuntu 12.04 cloud edition on Amazon - Apache2 - /etc

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have setup a web server on Amazon with 3 Virtual hosts. For some reason I can't get any of the sites going on it, they all show a 404 error. /var/log/apache2/error.log shows "File does not exist: /etc/apache2/htdocs"

I have checked:

- a2ensite all my virtual hosts
- actually checked softlinks in sites-enabled
- access rights in /var/www to 777, in case user is not www-data
- grep -r htdocs /etc/apache2 (returns nothing)
- ports.conf has NameVirtualHost directive exactly matching Virtual Hosts

What else could  this be?

```
ports.conf 

# If you just change the port or add more ports here, you will likely also
# have to change the VirtualHost statement in
# /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default
# This is also true if you have upgraded from before 2.2.9-3 (i.e. from
# Debian etch). See /usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/NEWS.Debian.gz and
# README.Debian.gz

NameVirtualHost 107.20.169.163:80
Listen 80

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    # If you add NameVirtualHost *:443 here, you will also have to change
    # the VirtualHost statement in /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl
    # to <VirtualHost *:443>
    # Server Name Indication for SSL named virtual hosts is currently not
    # supported by MSIE on Windows XP.
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>


sites-available/www.seleconlight.com


<VirtualHost 107.20.169.163:80>

ServerName www.seleconlight.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/www.seleconlight.com

CustomLog /var/log/apache2/www.seleconlight.com-access.log combined
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/www.seleconlight.com-error.log

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Your document root shouldn't be within `/etc`, it should be `/var/www` if that's what you're trying to use.  And you shouldn't use 777 permissions.  Do you have `DocumentRoot htdocs` configured in one of your vhosts or something?  Where'd these configs come from, and can you show them to us?

Comment: Pls see the vhost. I don't know where the /etc/apache/htdocs comes from, see my grep command.

Comment: I don't see why this has been downvoted, obviously I have already checked in 5 areas that work fine on the other 5 servers I manage

Comment: This may be an entirely side issue, but why are you trying to host www.seleconlight.com on 107... when is resolves and works (for me) on 119.47.125.193? What is the output of `apache2ctl -S` ?

Comment: Hi, the setup above is to move it from 119.47.125.193. apache2ctl -S:
VirtualHost configuration:
107.20.169.163:80      is a NameVirtualHost
         default server www.seleconlight.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.seleconlight.com:1)
         port 80 namevhost www.seleconlight.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/www.seleconlight.com:1)
Syntax OK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try to reinstall Apache with apt-get remove/ apt-get install

Answer (score 2):

Check your configuration files it looks like you've got a misconfigured [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#documentroot) directive.

You really don't want to have 777 perms anywhere in the web accessible part of your filesystem either.